# ¿Como puedo hacer que un FadeIn no se vea cuando recien carga la página?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una FadeIn y un FadeOut en mi sitio web, el problema es que cuando recien carga la página lo que se supone que debería ser invisible hasta ciertos pixeles aparece de primeras y cuanto hago scroll desaparece y cuando ya va en los pixeles que definí ahora si se ejecuta correctamente el FadeIn.

```
   (function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){                          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 320) {   //Donde se inicia el fade
                $('.top_header').fadeIn(320);  //Donde se inicia el fade-in
            } else {
                $('.top_header').fadeOut(320); //Donde se inicia el fade-out
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Mira también [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Además, ¿puedes crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Esto debería funcionar

```js
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var $header = $('.top-header')
    var $window = $(window)
    
    function toggleHeader() {
      if ($window.scrollTop() > 320) {
        $header.fadeOut(320)
      } else {
        $header.fadeIn(320)
      }
    }
    
    toggleHeader()
    
    $window.on('scroll', toggleHeader)
}(jQuery))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Por qué deberia funcionar? Recuerda que la explicacion es más importante que el codigo. Mira [answer] para mejorar tus respuestas. un saludo

Comment: No funcionó, ahora desde el inicio se ve lo que debería verse hasta el 'px' 320.

Comment: El problema es que el fade in solo se ejecuta en el evento scroll del objeto `window`, solo debes de poner un `$('.top_header').hide();` afuera del evento scroll para que se esconda cuando el documento este listo :)